# how to make php5 xmlParser to work on php4 server?

Tags: php, xml

I'm using this xml on a **php4 server**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<events>
    <record>
        <event>ticket</event>
        <eventDate>09/12/2010</eventDate>
        <desc>http://asce.co.il/page.asp?page_parent=611</desc>
    </record>
</events>
```

and i have this parser to be able **writing** on the xml file

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

$record = array(
    'event' => $_POST['event'],
    'eventDate' => $_POST['eventDate'],
    'desc' => $_POST['desc'],
);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'calendar.xml' );

$doc->formatOutput = true;

$r = $doc->getElementsByTagName("events")->item(0);
$b = $doc->createElement("record");

$event = $doc->createElement("event");
$event->appendChild(
    $doc->createTextNode( $record["event"] )
);
$b->appendChild( $event );

$eventDate = $doc->createElement("eventDate");
$eventDate->appendChild(
    $doc->createTextNode( $record["eventDate"] )
);
$b->appendChild( $eventDate );

$desc = $doc->createElement("desc");
$desc->appendChild(
    $doc->createTextNode( $record["desc"] )
);

$b->appendChild( $desc );
$r->insertBefore( $b,$r->firstChild );

$doc->save("calendar.xml");

header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");    
?>
```

It's all working great on a php5 server, But **my** problem is that **my server** have only **php4 support**

**what do i need to change in the script to be able using it on my server?** 
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOMDocument is not available for PHP4. As the [php manual page](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php) suggests, use [DOM XML](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/ref.domxml.php) for processing XML.

Comment: can you tell me, what is this in php4? $doc->formatOutput = true;

Comment: I'm not sure, but i think this indicates that the XML is marked up with tabs and new lines when echoed.